# IntelliJ Idea GUI Designer

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

I have created a project in intelliJ using the gui designer.

It works perfect when I run it from IntelliJ but when I create a jar file and run it all the components of the gui that I generated using the gui designer disappear.

I looked into the settings for the gui designer and there is an option

Generate GUI into

```
              (1) Binary Class Files

              (2) Java Source Code
```

Binary classs files is ticked.

Could that be it, I dont want to mess up everything.

Or is there something else I need to do to allow it to work